# How to show multiple values of an array at a time without using dbms_output.put_line in PL/SQL

Tags: plsql

I have an array which has dynamic index size. i want to show all the array values at a time with this

```
RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20010,'The Requirement index for item '|| 
                        (Here should be present all the array value) ||
                        ' needs to be in Approved status.');
```

statement.

Could anyone please help me out from this.

Advanced thanks to whom solved this issue.

Comment: What about concatenation within a for loop?

Comment: Could you please give an example for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have written a snippnet to replicate the scenario. Let me know if this helps.

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON;
DECLARE
TYPE AV_TAB
IS
  TABLE OF NUMBER;
  AV_TAB_NUM AV_TAB;
  LV_VAR VARCHAR2(32676);
BEGIN
  SELECT LEVEL BULK COLLECT INTO AV_TAB_NUM FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL < 10;
  FOR I IN AV_TAB_NUM.FIRST..AV_TAB_NUM.LAST
  LOOP
    lv_var:=lv_var||';'||AV_TAB_NUM(i);
  END LOOP;
  dbms_output.put_line(SUBSTR(LV_VAR,2,LENGTH(LV_VAR)));
EXCEPTION
WHEN OTHERS THEN
  RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20010,'The Requirement index for item '||lv_var ||' needs to be in Approved status.');
END;
```

Comment: I want the result when the exception will occur.

Comment: I got the answer.. Thanks for your help.